# Text not being highlighted on search in UIWebView using javascript

Tags: iphone, search, pdf, text, uiwebview

I have successfully implemented js code to highlight searched text.

But it does not work for my pdf file.

Is there any solution please help.

regards
aamir

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you can access the inner details of PDF files that are displayed by UIWebView.
Convert from pdf to html
I find solution at the:
http://zaldzbugz.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/how-to-implement-text-searching-inside-uiwebview/